# How can I determine if page is being viewed through lightbox?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, fancybox, lightbox

I have several sites I'm working on that are loading sub-pages via lightbox. The actual content is being found by Google, but the pages are hideous as they aren't meant to load all the headers and whatnot - this is content intended for lightbox delivery (ajax, fancybox).

In PHP, or javascript if necessary, how might I determine if the content is being viewed in a lightbox or not? Would be nice to throw up a "view the original page" link or something.

Comment: I know fancybox can handle AJAX data and iframes. If it's the latter, you can get the src of the iframe. If it's the former, you can wrap it in a div that maybe has a `data-url` attribute of the url.

Comment: I tried this `data-url` method and didn't seem to get it to do anything. Perhaps I'm not understanding it well enough. Best info I could find on it was here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fix-data-url-attribute-in-page-div-changes-url-path and that didn't have a ton of info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lightbox` like every other similar lib use AJAX for pulling content ... am not sure sure if you can detect if it is a standard `jquery` or `moottools` or `lightbox` because they all you the same technology

What you can do is detect if your page is been called via `AJAX`

```
function isAjax() {
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest");
}

if(isAjax())
{
    die("Don't Use AJAX");
}
else
{
    echo "WELCOME" ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lightboxes often use iframes to display external pages. If this is the case (you can inspect the Lightbox using Firebug to check this), you can use `window.top` on JavaScript to check this.

```
if (window.top.location != window.location) {
    //this page is inside a frame or iframe
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version of fancyBox with the default options then this trick should work -

```
<?php echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FANCYBOX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FANCYBOX']) ? 'is fancyBox' : 'is not fancyBox' ?>
```

Comment: Using Fancybox 2.1.5 which is current production version this reported "is not fancyBox" both in FancyBox and when page was loaded directly.